# How to check a label is checked or not with option

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I have a option which is in label control itself in Angular application.
[image: When No selected]

[image: When Yes selected]

If this is an normal option or checkbox controls i know to check if the control is checked or selected? but here how i can verify if the control is now in 'Yes' or 'No' state? I have enclosed the html content for this control and plese help me.

```
<div class="borrower-information__form-control switch-checkbox">
<input id="isAccountControllerAsPrimaryBorrower" class="toggle-checkbox ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" name="isAccountControllerAsPrimaryBorrower" data-ng-model="newController.controller.isAccountControllerAsPrimaryBorrower" aria-invalid="false" style="" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="isAccountControllerAsPrimaryBorrower" data-ng-attr-data-label="{{newController.booleanToString(newController.controller.isAccountControllerAsPrimaryBorrower)}}" data-label="Yes">Is primary borrower incapacitated?</label>
</div>
```

FYI... when i inspected this control with firepath, it highlights the label tag (blue dashed lines show in the picture).

Comment: I guess you mean JavaScript not Java, don't you?

Comment: I do it in Cucumber, Java, Selenium...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebElement webElement = //
String dataLabel = webElement.getAttribute("data-label");
boolean isChecked = dataLabel.equals("Yes") ? true : false;
```

Comment: Yes. Exactly works what i need and able to proceed further. Thanks much.